# Dockerfile RUN vs run image and use /bin/bash provides different result

Tags: linux, bash, docker, dockerfile

I have a simple dockerfile, something like

```
FROM spotify/cassandra

RUN sed -i -e "s/^authenticator:.*/authenticator: PasswordAuthenticator/" $CASSANDRA_CONFIG/cassandra.yaml \
&& sed -i -e "s/^authorizer:.*/authorizer: org.apache.cassandra.auth.CassandraAuthorizer/" $CASSANDRA_CONFIG/cassandra.yaml

RUN cassandra \
&& sleep 10 && echo "Applying CQL scripts..." \
&& cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra -f someScript
&& pkill -f cassandra
```

If I do everything from build command

```
docker build --no-cache=true --rm=true .
```

I get exception "AuthenticationException(why='Username and/or password are incorrect"

But If I create the image withour last command and start it with

```
docker run --rm -i -t --entrypoint=/bin/bash my-image
```

and then repeat all commands I get no exceptions.

What is the difference? How could it be, that second way works and first doesn't?

I noticed that in the first case during start cassandra doesn't print:

```
ERROR 22:39:03,081 Directory /var/lib/cassandra/data doesn't exist
ERROR 22:39:03,084 Directory /var/lib/cassandra/commitlog doesn't exist
ERROR 22:39:03,085 Directory /var/lib/cassandra/saved_caches doesn't exist
```

I may only guess that as RUN is running commands in a separate container it is somehow doesn't see some files which are changed in spotify/cassandra...

spotify/cassandra repo is here: https://github.com/spotify/docker-cassandra

UPD. I think I get the reason, it's because spotify cassandra configuration files are modified in entrypoint script, thus these changes are not available when I perform RUN command.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to perform initialization for your database, you should do it when container starts. Dockerfile is not a suitable place for that. Consider the following example:

**entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

sed -e

cassandra \
&& sleep 10 && echo "Applying CQL scripts..." \
&& cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra -f someScript
&& pkill -f cassandra

exec "$@"
```

**Dockefile**

```
FROM spotify/cassandra
(...)
ADD ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

Now try to `docker run --rm -it your-image`. If all goes well, you'll see that your database has been initialized.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but what if I want to execute scripts prior to container start? I don't want to create cassandra keyspaces/tables each time I start container..

Comment: This script will be executed only once when container is being created. If you do `docker stop` and `docker start` again, you'll see that initialization does not repeat.

Comment: Ok, that's great, but I still don't understand what is the difference. spotify/cassandra configures cassandra settings in entrypoint, I decided to RUN their entrypoint script and apply my script. But nothing changed. So, when I do:
RUN cassandra-singlenode && sleep 10 && echo "Applying CQL scripts..."  && cqlsh -u cassandra -p cassandra -f script
I still see that cassandra starts in another way than running ENTRYPOINT ["cassandra-singlenode"]. I need to understand why it happens and can't find any info on the web.

Comment: Looks like there is no difference, both ways are printing directory errors. The reason why RUN way fails is just because of small timeout. Cassandra didn't have time to initialize AUTH machinery...